# ¿como puedo declarar una variable en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

necesito declarar una variable timestamp en postgresql pero cuando lo intento me da error de sintaxis, si alguien pudiera darme el codigo de como declarar y asignar valor a una variable seria de mucha ayuda, gracias

Comment: se hacerlo en sql server pero en postgree no me sale, alquien puede ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma declaras variables:

```
user_id integer;
quantity numeric(5);
url varchar;
myrow tablename%ROWTYPE;
myfield tablename.columnname%TYPE;
arow RECORD;
```

Si deseas declarar una variable timestamp por ejemplo en una funcion de esta forma te puede servir:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION test3() RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
_currenttime timestamp := now();
BEGIN
copy (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE createdtime < _currenttime - INTERVAL '1 days') TO '/tmp/table1.csv';
END
$$;
```

Para ejecutar la funcion:

```
Select test3();
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar una variable es:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba (
    "Fecha" timestamp(6) with time zone
)
```

Para agregar/dar de alta un registro:

```
INSERT INTO prueba VALUES ('2018-09-29 19:10:25-07');
```